# How can I use Java Spring Service like RMI In Nodejs？ Anybody knows it？

Tags: java, node.js

How can I use Java Spring Service like RMI In Nodejs? Anybody knows it?

Comment: Perhaps take a look at http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html ?

Answer (score 0):

RMI have very specific binary protocol. It will be difficult to decode/encode it in Java Script. I suggest to use REST web services and exchange with Json messages.

Comment: hehe!   I  have the same idea using rest web services,as you say It will be difficult to decode/encode it in Java Script ,  I will make it a choice.   Thank you!